# NAS Synology Scheduled task: how to catch PHP script error?

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks, nas, synology

How to catch PHP script's error string in a NAS Synology Scheduled task?
I've checked "send an email with the execution result, and only if an error occurs, but this mail only tells me somethink like with "exit with error code 255".
I tried in my PHP script:

```
if ($something_is_wrong) trigger_error("An error explanation to undersatnd what happened in this damned script.");
```

But the error report mail still reports a 255 error, without any error string.

Synology task scheduler:
[image]

Comment: How do you execute this piece of PHP code?

Comment: PHP files are located in /home/admin/ folder and executed from the built-in Task Scheduler. All is working fine, except error catching.